Remove VS Code in WSL
After typing code . in WSL running Ubuntu 24.04, VS Code automatically installed itself. I am now trying to uninstall it, but cannot find it anywhere. sudo apt purge code, sudo apt-get purge code, sudo dpkg --purge code, and sudo snap remove --purge code all tell me that code was not installed. The same holds for alternative names, incl. vscode and visual-studio-code. When I enter code ., VS Code opens though. It clearly is installed.
I want to keep the Windows version of VS Code, but remove its Linux installation. Do you know how I can do that?
Edit:
To clarify questions in the comments:

I have simply entered code ., nothing else. Unexpectedly, that was enough to trigger an installation. This behavior might be specific to WSL.
snap list tells me that no snaps are installed. Anything installed with sudo snap install --classic should show up there.


"...all tell me that code was not installed." Almost. They are saying that they were unaware of any code installation, as those tools were not used to install. apt and snap are package managers, and they only speak their packages and nothing else. They are not system-wide master controls.

A link in your question above to whatever instructions you used to install code would be helpful.

This question is similar to: Does a snap for vscode exist?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Please do not add "Solved" to your question.  Solutions should be posted as an Answer, which you can self-accept after a few days.  That allows people to vote on the solution separately from the question.  I've rolled back your question to remove the "Solved" part, but you are welcome to add it to an answer if you want.  I think my answer below is actually what you experienced, but let me know.

What you likely saw, when you typed code . for the first time in WSL, was the installation of the "server" shim that VSCode uses to communicate with WSL:
> code .
Installing VS Code Server for Linux x64 (4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 1765 files and folders to /home/ntd/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3.
Looking for compatibility check script at /home/ntd/.vscode-server/bin/4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3/bin/helpers/check-requirements.sh
Running compatibility check script
Compatibility check successful (0)

As you can see from the output above, this is stored in a hidden (dot-prefixed) .vscode-server directory under your home directory.
If you don't plan on using VSCode from within Ubuntu/WSL, you can simple remove it via:
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server

Running code again will simply regenerate it if needed. You may need to reinstall any extensions you added to the "Remote: WSL" session.
